# Complex "indirect" associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a Like model with a liked_id and a user_id. And a Message model to_id and from_id.

```rb
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :liked, :class_name => "User"
   validates_presence_of :user_id
   validates_presence_of :liked_id

   def latest_message
     Message.where(["(to_id = ? AND from_id = ?) OR (to_id = ? AND from_id = ?)", self.liked_id, self.user_id, self.user_id, self.liked_id]).order("created_at DESC").limit(1).first
   end
end


class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :to, :class_name => "User"
   belongs_to :from, :class_name => "User"
   validates_presence_of :to_id, :from_id, :content
end
```

I want to be able to set up an association between the like and the message and be able to pull it back in one query.

At the moment I am using the :method => [:latest_message] option in my json serialisation. But it isn't very performant.

Can a complex association like this be made where the primary and foreign keys are AND ORs like in the where statement in the latest_message? Ideally I want a has_one :latest_message

Comment: Have you looked up a many to many association? ( Message has_many :like :through => 'User' ) Im not a rails guy so forgive the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an association extension. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions